# Black screen when saving Image

Tags: android, eclipse

I am making my first android game that lets the user design a horse and I want the user to save their work when they are done and display it into a gallery type but when ever I try to save the image, all I get is a black screen instead of the image. I have been using the KiloBolt frame work for the project. i believe the reason I get a black screen is because a view is never really created with it since it relies on a screen format without a layout. So how do I get a view with it if that is the problem or is the problem the way I am saving the file? If there is any other Code you need let me know and I will post it.

Code for saving

```
 private void takeScreenshot() {

            Date now = new Date();
            android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

            try {
                // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
                String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".png";

                // create bitmap screen capture

                View  v1 =  ((Activity) game).getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

               int width = v1.getWidth();
                int height = v1.getHeight();

                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    v1.draw(c);

                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                File imageFile = new File(mPath);

                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile );

                int quality = 100;
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("CAB", "error" + e);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Since i can't find an answer I will just rebuild from the start and not use KiloBolt. I will try using views for each screen instead and info from other things that I have learned.